# using preg_replace or preg_match_all function to replace a string

Tags: php, html, regex

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="">
```

I am trying to remove the value="" from the string using preg_replace can anyone help I am not clued up with regex at all

Comment: ... _can anyone help I am not clued up with regex at all_ ➜ ___[Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/5698098)___

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `preg_replace` if it's only `value=""`. Use `str_replace` which is faster than using regex.

```
$string = '<input type="text" name="name" value="">';

print(str_replace('value=""','',$string)); //<input type="text" name="name" >
```